# javascript steps climbing with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

My problem is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318145/counting-ways-to-climb-n-steps-with-1-2-or-3-steps-taken) , but the only difference is that I have to return the number of ways in which the steps can be climbed according to a given array of permitted steps. For example, if steps to be climbed are `4` and the permitted steps are `[1,3]`, the result should be `3`. Combinations:`[(1,1,1,1),(1,3),(3,1)]`

I tried to modify the code as :

```
function add(x,arr){
let result = 0
   if(x<0)
      return 0;

   if(x===0)
      return 1;

   else{for(let i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){
        result += add(x-arr[i]);
      }
      return result};  
}
add(4,[1,3])
```

but this returns an error saying `cannot read property length of "undefined"`.How do I correct this?

Comment: How do you call `add(x, arr)`?  The message would clearly indicate that `arr` is `undefined`

Comment: `add(x-arr[i]);` <--- tada

Comment: sorry I didn't include that.That's what it says after calling add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your else condition,

```
result += add(x-arr[i])
```

Should be

```
result += add(x-arr[i], arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I misread the question at first, and was happy to show how to convert a recursive function which counts the results to one which lists them.  As I came here to post it, I realized that this was not what was asked, but I still find it a nice example of how one might go about this... so I'm posting it anyway.  :-)

A straightforward counting solution, similar to the one in the question (with the fix from Abbas Cyclewala) could be structured like this:

```js
const count = (n, ss) =>
  n < 0 ? 
    0 
  : n == 0 ? 
    1 
  :   // else
    ss.map(s => count(n - s, ss))
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

console .log (
  count (4, [1, 3])  //~> 3
)
```

We can switch to a list of results instead of the count by noting that the equivalent of `0` is `[]`, of `1` is `[[]]` and instead of adding all the recursive results, we need to simply concatenate them.  That leaves only an update to the actual recursive results, which is not difficult: if the first step is of length `k`, recurse on `(n - k)`, and prepend `k` to each result.

You can see how structurally similar these are:

```js
const paths = (n, ss) => 
  n < 0 ? 
    [] 
  : n == 0 ? 
    [[]]
  :   // else
    ss.map(s => paths(n - s, ss).map(ps => [s, ...ps]))
      .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])

console .log (
  paths (4, [1, 3]) //~> [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 3], [3, 1]]
)
```

So this doesn't answer the original question, but if someone wants it, here it is!